# For React Frontend Application, Bootstrap vs Material-UI

Tags: material-ui, react-bootstrap

We are creating application with ReactJS as frontend.
For look n feel, what is the preferred option Material-UI or BootStrap.

Priority is Stability. Which UI Library is more stable for ReactJS

regards

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are stable. 
Material UI is the most popular when you are using ReactJS for UI, and in my opinion, the interface was simple. It's really good if you make a mobile app with that.

Bootstrap in other side was popular too. It's mobile friendly and you can make columns, alerts, and stuff like that which is handy. Most of web programmer use this bootstrap. So I think you can make better web interface with that.

I suggest you to use both of them for more better interface.

You can check another answer in the same question here: [Bootstrap vs Material UI for React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831331/bootstrap-vs-material-ui-for-react)

Comment: Thanks Miruku, If on stability both are equal then by design which is better. Your answer give me 2 direction.

Comment: For the first answer in my mind if you ask about simplicity is Material UI. But in other hand, Bootstrap is great when you are creating responsive web application. So it depends.

Comment: Hi Miruku, I have template with HTML and Bootstrap and it look awesome, but when I try to map the same using Raect-Bootstrap, all are not coverd spacing and some ui got effected.. should I user plain bootstrap using className when required ot its bad idea?