# React - Material UI vs Reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm going to start a react project. I want a little clarification about the choice of Material UI over Reactstrap. Material UI is better than Bootstrap as mentioned in another comparison of [Bootstrap vs Material UI for React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831331/bootstrap-vs-material-ui-for-react). But I'm a little confused about Reactstrap after going through [Pros & Cons of Material UI and Reactstrap](https://stackshare.io/stackups/material-ui-vs-reactstrap#:%7E:text=Material%2DUI%3A%20React%20components%20for,4%20components%20compatible%20with%20React.&text=Material%2DUI%20and%20reactstrap%20are%20both%20open%20source%20tools.) as shown in the below images. Or should I use both of them as per requirement in the same project?

[image: Pros of Material UI and Reactstrap]
[image: Cons of Material UI and Reactstrap]

I would like to use ready made UI components like Collapse-able Side Menu, Tables with pagination, Auto complete Select etc.

Comment: These cons seem fairly opinionated. There's not a single source that approves or disapproves of libraries. You can use whatever suits your needs. It's also worth considering React Bootstrap over Reactstrap.

Comment: Would you please justify your comment in an answer if you have time?

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you're looking for. I don't believe I would have an objective answer anyway.

Comment: I'm simply looking for the scenarios where I should prefer React Bootstrap or Reactstrap over Material UI

Comment: I've been using Material-UI for the past 3 years and it's highly recommended. Somebody correct me if I'm wrong but I believe Reactstrap is only offering UI components while Material-UI provides utility components, hooks, helpers and the theme customization along with its fully customizable UI components.

Comment: Ok Thanks, can please put your suggestions in an answer

Comment: Bootstrap will look like Twitter, Material will look more like Google, that's all.

Comment: Okay! A Great conclusion! Thanks for your participation.

Comment: Opinionated question ! I hate Material-UI. is my answer valid ? yes, to me it is. It's like unlearning HTML and learning a totally new syntax. No thanks !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

react-bootstrap is more popular than reactstrap. I will speak about react-bootstrap and Material UI.

I have more experience with Material UI. I don't even know how Material UI became that popular while it was very bad when it was released. It used inline styling and it was a nightmare to customize anything. Its performance was very poor. Still, it became very popular and it improved a lot. I used it in my latest project and the performance was great and I used its new CSS in JS solution combined with styled-components. I think it will be a bit harder to use than react-bootstrap but it has more components out of the box.

For most people, react-bootstrap would be an easier choice.

I can't tell you which one to use but I can give you some things to think about and decide yourself:

1. Which design do you prefer?
2. If you have more experience with bootstrap, go with react-bootstrap.
3. If you prefer sass go with react-bootstrap. If you prefer CSS in JS go with Material UI.
4. If react-bootstrap is missing some components you would need that exists in Material UI go with Material UI but remember that you can add other external components to your project anyway so I think this may not be a limitation.

Comment: Good Luck Dear! Nice to see an energetic Front-end Developer from Egypt!

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your choices, yes, it's a little bit of complicated to customized material, but the looks and feels is outstanding, for tables and all, better to use Material-UI it has inbuilt pagination if you are not comfortable in that you can try this one it also comes inbuilt pagination and much more [https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/)

Comment: The link you attached is not working. I think you mean https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/table/

Comment: Moreover you are suggesting Material UI but attached a link to React Bootstrap table?

Comment: that's another option if you don't wanna use material UI tables and all, you can follow up, here is the working link [https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2) @MuhammadUmarFarooq

Answer (score 3):

I agree with comments about the *cons* referred in your question seems to be more opinions than facts; probably the only fact we can say after compare the two packages is that Material UI has some more built in components.

Once said that it's hard to take a decision without knowing the specification of your project.

Probably the best suggestion we can give you is simply use the one you are more comfortable with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect project requirements

Comment: AFAIK @MuhammadUmarFarooq reactstrap doesn't have tables with pagination

Answer (score 3):

Refer to my experience, if it is an commerial/external project that needs minimal branding, and you are looking for basic reuse-able component to create Admin Portal or CMS, I prefer reactstrap/CoreUI. My main concern is Theme Overriding.

1. Not enough documentation about overriding material ui style, had quite a hard time to edit and test the theme setting again and again, while reactstrap/CoreUI allow you to import your own .css file, or overriding its class css. So you can simply change the textfield padding at once in css while your designer request to.
2. Neither material ui and reactstrap/CoreUI can fulfil your need. You may install other useful npm like react-select, multiple datetime picker, autosize textarea, or color picker. Then you try to make its style to be consistent as other Textfield. Styling a component like material ui is quite hard because of its behavior, e.g. label zoom out while focus. But Styling like reactstrap/CoreUI is much easier, you can even reuse the bootstrap classname.

If you are trying to deliver something fast & small without designer, material ui is a good choice, cover most of your use cases. If it is a long-term project and designer is watching you, I am afraid material ui is not a good choice.

Anyway, case by case.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is your Choice. But if you are good at bootstrap-4, best to go with `Reactstrap` which is component based library for react.

In  my Company we are using `Reactstrap` and things go quite well. But this doesn't mean we are not using our own media queries and flexbox,styled-jsx which we obviously do.

Even though you will be using ready made Components available in `Reactstrap`, as you progress in the project you will have to use other libraries '`React-Final-Forms`' to handle forms and form data efficiently having high performance when compared with normal forms available in ReactStrap.

Similarly you will need  a library known as '`React-select`' to handle drop downs, which will give me more options than normal `ReactStrap` select form Component.

Comment: Brother in react project, when deciding on css, you should use node-sass and change all the css files with .scss. This will give you more control on writing css and expose you to different techniques as well. I would like to help you in your React Project that you are about to start, we can collaborate and learn from one another. I already have 3 years of experience in Front End and 1.8 years in React. If you seek any help please let me know. I am here for my brother

Comment: Isn't every implementation of Sass other than Dart Sass deprecated? The Dart implementation packaged for npm is named `sass`, not `node-sass`.

Comment: @DDMC Yes Mate! I also checked the same. Packages keep updating from time to time. It's been more than a year that I haven't been in touch with ReactJS. In fact 15 months to be very precise. But what you mentioned is true. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594119/node-sass-usage-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-major-version

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As for now, I am doing project on Next.js and Material-UI. I was also looking for such comparison between Bootstrap(reactstrap)/Material/Ant. And I am agreed with [Daniel Ricci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4690946/daniele-ricci) with choosing Material-UI.

Why's that?

First of all, I have spoken with my better experienced friend (he has contributed to his own [(DEVExpress) React Component Library](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/React_Components/DevExtreme_React_Components/), so he was know what he has talking about)

Project Management Side pros:

Material itself has a [very useful style guidelines from Google](https://material.io/design). So it is also not about library components, but about styles / colors / design. So you could always customize yourself and [create your own theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/). But as for you, it will be easier to understand why you are using Roboto:400 at H3 title, and «[what color I should pick as secondary?](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors)», if you decide to choose primary color.

As a result, it's much easier to find a UI/UX designer for your project. And you always know how your project should looks like.

Default react [Material-UI component library](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/example-projects/) is quite rich and very good described with examples. (As you may already noticed). And also there are a lot of plugin libraries components, which is ready-to-use out of the box. In my own case I was needed for a editable material react tables, and have found them [in via google in 5 seconds or so](https://material-table.com/#/). In my project **tables are everything** and they present the product (price comparison) so that's why I choose material myself.

You could compare component libraries via google trends or github stars, but in your own case with: *Collapse-able Side Menu, Tables with pagination, Auto complete Select* I would choose MaterialUI.

As for cons, visually Material Style is very populated by devs (cause it's Android's app default theme) and some people thinks that it looks a bit *ugly*, but I thought it couldn't be a problem because you could always customize your own theme.

And as mentioned Kleo is [his original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53796656/7475615):

> *If you have the time, dedication and resources, there is really nothing wrong with mixing them together. But you just need to think about the time/cost/benifit of it. DIY to make the end user happy, even if you mix them. Totally yourself is remaking the wheel, but you can always pull in boostrap styles etc.*