# 'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version

Tags: angular

When I upgraded from Angular **8** to **11** I faced this warning

> 'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. To opt-out of the deprecated behavior and start using 'sass' uninstall 'node-sass'.

can anyone help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the question here? But since the package is deprecated and will be removed in the future, I suggest listening to the advice on the package's website, ie switching to Dart Sass (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass).

Comment: You might find what you are looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320691/switching-from-node-sass-to-dart-sass-in-my-angular-cli-project?rq=1

Comment: This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62347652/3701011

Answer (score 30):

The full error message is

`'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. To opt-out of the deprecated behaviour and start using 'sass' uninstall 'node-sass'.`

So, I think the only solution that you can try is obvious, just uninstall node-sass.

=> I already uninstalled it and tried `ng serve` and `ng build --prod` all is working fine.

FYI, I as a developer always have found this library `node-sass` as a pain in the head because of its incompatibility errors. I am happy that we don't have to use it and deal with its painful errors anymore.

Comment: Are you using sass in your project? Because uninstalling node-sass and not doing anything else is not enough.

Comment: Yes sir I am using scss files inside my apps and it is working fine.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the information. It wasn't enough for me.

Comment: This change creates an issue with relative urls in the scss files.
See :
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12797#issuecomment-598534241

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution to this issue? I'm facing the the same problem in my project . @Laker

Comment: You will need to install `sass` which is the dart version of sass.

Answer (score 29):

Try replacing 'node-sass' with 'sass'

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm i -S sass
```

Comment: This is the real solution.

Comment: This is the actual answer :) Keep it up @jie Thank you

Answer (score 8):

```
$ npm uninstall node-sass
```

**This will fix the following error also.**

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):
Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  source-map information is not available at url() declaration (found orphan CR, try removeCR option)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can replace node-sass with sass, which is the dart version of sass.

### npm

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

### Yarn

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```

If you're using gulp, make sure to update your build script with the correct usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass

Answer (score 4):

After uninstalling I was still getting the same error.

I had a look at the source code, turns out the check is quite fragile:

```
  try {
        sassImplementation = require('node-sass');
        wco.logger.warn(`'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. ` +
            `To opt-out of the deprecated behaviour and start using 'sass' uninstall 'node-sass'.`);
    }
```

Which means that, if you have node-sass installed globally, or in a parent directory somewhere, you'll get this warning.

To test this, make a new file in your project directory and run it with node:

```
const t = require('node-sass');

console.log(t);
```

If you don't get module_not_found, it means it's node_sass is being resolved.
In my case I had node-sass installed under my user home directory.

Comment: After uninstalling node-sass (in an Angular project and globally) the error hasnt gone away for me either. In the package-lock file i still find references to node-sass as optional peerdependency of sass-loader which in turn is a required package for angular-devkit/build-angular. any idea how I should proceed?

Comment: My case is the same, I'm trying to migrate Angular and Angular Material from v11 to v12. My Angular project is under a parent directory which uses `node-sass`. Due to how Node resolves modules, it tries to look up the parent directory till the root before reporting not finding `node-sass` and use `sass` instead. From Angular v13, they will remove `node-sass` completely: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/21455

Answer (score 4):

currently (december 2021) it is installed with

```
npm install -g sass
```

https://sass-lang.com/install