# Error installing node-sass in a Sylius project

Tags: php, node.js, npm, node-sass, sylius

So I'm about starting learning php framework called Sylius, in the installation steps, there was a yarn command which should install all the node modules needed, but an error in installing node-sass showed up like bellow, I have already tried so much answer from other similar questions, but nothing of these tries could fix this issue.

```
ThinkPad@DESKTOP-RCHEDFO MINGW64 ~/Desktop/desk/Projects/MyFirstShop
$ npm install node-sass
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-inject@2.2.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-inject.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-node-resolve@3.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-node-resolve.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@3.0.7: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated assets-webpack-plugin@3.10.0: This version should have more strictly enforced the change to versions of node >10.x.x
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see request/request#3142
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-commonjs@9.3.4: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-commonjs.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\desk\Projects\MyFirstShop\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\desk\Projects\MyFirstShop\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli 'C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\desk\Projects\MyFirstShop\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli 'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.10.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:/python39/python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb which succeeded C:/python39/python.exe C:\python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\python39\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack File "", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\desk\Projects\MyFirstShop\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ThinkPad\Desktop\desk\Projects\MyFirstShop\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\ThinkPad\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-29T17_48_14_134Z-debug.log
```

Any help with this error ? it really got my noise...

Comment: From [Sass node package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) they said _Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated._ So, you should use other package instead of `node-sass`. I recommend use `sass` instead. Or read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594119/node-sass-usage-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-major-version).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this a while back and it is a known issue

I posted my findings [here](https://forum.sylius.com/t/install-error-node-sass/1959/6) but in order to keep things clear on this page:

- Update to `gulp-sass` version 5.x (I did 5.1 at the time; haven't checked to see if there has been further updates) and add `sass`: `yarn add --dev gulp-sass@^5.1.0 sass` (or equivalent `npm`).
- Edit the Sylius AdminBundle and ShopBundle gulpfile.babel.js files (in the `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle` directory) with the following changes:

  - Remove `import sass from 'gulp-sass';`
  - Add the following lines:

    ```js
    import realSass from 'sass';
    import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
    const sass = gulpSass(realSass)
    ```

  Note that this change will potentially be overridden with a Sylius upgrade (and will not be tracked by your version control if you are using it), so is not recommended for long-term.

I believe there is an issue raised for this problem in the Sylius repository but I can't find it at the moment sorry.